# JSF Controller vs Struts Controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsf, jakarta-ee, struts

I have read somewhere that

> Developer can access the struts controller by creating an Action
>   object that can 
>       integrate with the controller whereas Java Server Faces technology does not 
>       allow access to the controller.

Can anyone please elaborate this for me, what does it mean?any example would be a great help.

Also

> The Struts controller can do things like access control on each Action
>   based on
>       user roles. This functionality is not provided by JSF.

I am confused on this point too. Please explain this for me with an example.

Answer (score 0):

When you are coding for Struts 2 ( also true for Struts ) you are extending the framework at the controller itself.  The Action, which is a base class that you extend with your own actions, allows you to extend the controller logic, typically by making some calls out to business logic, and then redirecting to one of your result views ( known as "Results" in s2 ) based upon the outcome of that logic.  Of course, you can do stuff like access control on an action; but you can do anything on an action.  I guess this snippet of a quote is just pointing out that the conceptual granularity of Struts 2 is in synch with a per request instance of the Action ( controller ).

As for JSF, it's a completely different type of framework.  Instead of being "Request" oriented like Struts 2, it's "component oriented".  This means that the conceptual granularity of JSF is the notion of a component widget on the page.  This is somehow at a different level, or perhaps orthogonal to, the way struts 2 makes it all about the processing of a single request. So, in JSF, the framework is more deeply hiding the controller logic, mostly because it's more complicated.  The controller logic must take the incoming data from a request and make sure it then get's mapped and delivered to the appropriate component widgets on the page associated with the request.  The developers api is all about the component contract.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an example.
Let's say you have a jsp file with a form like this:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="<%=formAction%>" method="post">

</form>
```

Which contains some inputs. On the top of your jsp, you can define your action like:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="formAction">
<portlet:param name="action" value="submitForm"/>
</portlet:actionURL>
```

So when you click your submit button for that form, your controller's processAction method does what you define for it's action, like:

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
if ("submitForm".equals(action)) {

   //do something

}
```

Regards !

Comment: but how it is different from JSF Controller ? I asked their difference.

Comment: you can use tags like <jsp:useBean id="myvar" class="java.lang.String" scope="request"></jsp:useBean> to make myvar available from the controller to jsp, it's kind of better communication between them.

Comment: I actually want to understand the difference between Struts Controller and JSF controller and also the statements that I mentioned above in my question what do they mean.. I asked for the code in reference of those two statements to understand the difference